# Determine the following limits $\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sin x + \frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{\sin x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Determine the following limits

1. $\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sin x + \frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)$
2. $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{\sin x}$

Comment: For 1, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152605/201168). For 2, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1375382/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/)*)

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sin(x)+\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)=0+\lim_{x \to 0}e^x=1$$
further we get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{\sin(x)}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x}{\cos(x)}=1$$

Comment: Funny: the OP tagged his question **"limits-without-l'Hospital"**, yet both these limits are calculated *via l'Hospital* in this answer...and it gets accepted...

Answer (score 2):

For example, using the definition of derivative:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x\cdot\frac x{\sin x}=e'(0)\cdot1=1$$

Can you now do the other one?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Recall that $e^x=1+x+o_{x\to 0}(x)$ and $\sin(x)=x+o_{x\to 0}(x)$. These asymptotics are derived from [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem).